# Get Request IDs when user clicks "Send Request" on Facebook Request UI

Tags: javascript, facebook

The Facebook documentation for user-initiated [App Request Dialogues](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) says that `FB.ui` should return a csv list of `request_ids` that were sent out by the user when they click "Send Request"

I'm totally lost as to when and how to retrieve this list.  Do you have to bind an event to the "Send Request" button?  How can you get back the Request IDs when a user sends out requests?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the list as soon as the send the requests. You can use ajax to send it to your server if you want:

```
FB.ui({
         'method':  'apprequests',
         'message': request_message
      }, 
      function(response){
        // response.request_ids contains comma separated list of ids.
      }
);
```